# detect thunderbolt display connection and switch bluetooth accordingly

Tags: mac, bluetooth, thunderbolt-display

I have a thunderbolt display that I use as a docking station with wireless keyboard and mouse.

Is there a way to turn on bluetooth when connecting the display and turn it off when disconnecting the display?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/) can do what you want. It's pretty versatile, but you can certainly build a rule that will turn on your Bluetooth when a specific display is attached.

Comment: +1 ControlPlane.  Works great.  I use it to turn my BT, open some websites, etc on when I get to work by detecting a specific magsafe adapter and my TB connection.